# Slim log in from any page and redirect back

Tags: php, authentication, slim

I want to place a login form on every page of my site. I've set up a post route in Slim, which is also used for a 'normal' login that will just send users to the homepage. Just wondering what is the best way to then redirect back to the page they were on.

E.G User is on 'About us' page, fills in credentials on that page, if successful, send the user back to that page.

One idea I thought of, was to send the current URL along in the form as POST data, check for this existence in the post route and redirect if present? Wondered if there were any tricks I were missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your method of sending the current URL in the form as POST data sounds good. There are a couple PHP frameworks which employ this method using GET data. If you pull this value from `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` in Apache you should be good to go.